# Chaining html5 videos with Video.Js

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I am looking fore some code allowing me to launch automatically a video after another one.
I'am using the great video.js library, which has a quite complete API. I found some snippet to  get an event listener working at the end of the 1st video, but then I cannot launch the second one.

This is working, displaying an alert at the end of the 1st video :

```
_V_("intro").ready(function(){
this.addEvent("ended", function(){
    alert('foo');
});
});
```

And this is also working, launching a video in fullscreen on page reload :

```
_V_("leader").ready(function(){
var leader = this;
leader.requestFullScreen();
leader.play();
});
```

**But I can't get the 2nd video launching in fullscreen at the end of 1st video...**

Last subtility, I would like to entirely build the 2nd video with javascript, not having to write it and just hiding id with CSS.

Thank you folks !
Elliot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the provided 'src' method in the Video.js API, if you want to play a second video right after the first one finishes it would work like this:

```
_V_("intro").ready(function(){
    this.addEvent("ended", function(){
        this.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: "http://path/to/second/video.mp4" });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest and most direct approach.

I'm currently writing a playlist class extension for video.js that has this ability but will be sometime before its released because it is for my employer first.

Comment: Instead of this.addEvent, you can also use the video.js method "on".